How do I pass a parameter value in a function when using a join?
I am finding other solutions. I know my SQL Server query is not correct, but I need help to resolve the issue.
Below is my query and what I want to achieve with it for better understanding.
Gettring error like that

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The multi-part identifier "c.CountryCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The multi-part identifier "c.Contact" could not be bound.

DECLARE @BusinessId NVARCHAR(100) = '99969011-7b1d-4c2d-92a6-fba9ca31a261',
    @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'ece85174-fafd-43fb-a7a6-04c051f74de9';

DECLARE @RoleName NVARCHAR(50),
    @BusinessPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(20);

-- Get the business phone number
SELECT TOP(1) @BusinessPhoneNumber = bm.PhoneNumberID 
FROM BusinessDetails_Metas bm
INNER JOIN BusinessDetails b ON 
    bm.BusinessId = CAST(b.Id AS NVARCHAR(100))
WHERE bm.BusinessId = @BusinessId;

-- Get the role name of the user
SELECT TOP(1) @RoleName = r.[Name]
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN Role r ON r.Id = u.RoleId
WHERE u.Id = @UserId;

-- Main query to retrieve contact details and last conversation information
SELECT 
 c.ContactId,
 c.[Name],
 c.BusinessId,
 c.UserId,
 REPLACE(c.CountryCode, '+', '') + c.Contact AS Contact,
 c.ChatStatus,
 c.UserId AS Assignee,
 c.Tags,
 conv.TextMessage AS LastMessage,
 conv.CreatedAt AS LastMessageAt,
 c.IsSpam
FROM BusinessDetails_Metas bm
INNER JOIN BusinessDetails b ON bm.BusinessId = CAST(b.Id AS NVARCHAR(100))
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.CompanyId = bm.BusinessId
INNER JOIN Contacts c ON c.BusinessId = b.Id AND c.IsActive = 1
LEFT JOIN dbo.GetLastConversation(@BusinessPhoneNumber, REPLACE(c.CountryCode, '+', '') + c.Contact) conv ON 
 (conv.[From] = REPLACE(c.CountryCode, '+', '') + c.Contact OR conv.[To] = REPLACE(c.CountryCode, '+', '') + c.Contact)
WHERE b.Id = @BusinessId
 AND (@RoleName IN ('Admin', 'Owner') 
 OR (@RoleName NOT IN ('Admin', 'Owner') AND c.UserId = @UserId));


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastConversation]
(
    @WhatsappPhoneNumberId NVARCHAR(20),
    @ToNumberId  NVARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM Conversations
    WHERE ([From] = @WhatsappPhoneNumberId AND [To] = @ToNumberId)
       OR ([From] = @ToNumberId AND [To] = @WhatsappPhoneNumberId)
    ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
);
GO


I created a new function to achieve the last conversation message and also tried using a subquery, but I was unable to resolve the issue. I am looking for a better solution.
What should I do?

change LEFT JOIN to OUTER APPLY

it's work but coming duplicate row

That's a completely different question. Who know what your data is supposed to be

Normally I asked you! When I didn't use outer apply with that function the duplicate data was not coming....but thanks for the help

Yes, because it was an error? But i don't know, you have TOP 1 so there shouldn't be more than 1 row?

Selecting TOP *n* without an ORDER BY can produce different results between query executions.
